# Hostinger, what is the url of database

Tags: database, persistence

I am trying to connect to my hostinger database but it does not work:

```
<property name = "javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value = "jdbc:mysql://mysql.hostinger.fr/myDBName"/>
```

I have the following error:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: mysql.hostinger.fr: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hostinger does not allow you to connect remotely on your database with a basic free account. You need to deploy your application to test the connection.